# tor-browser connection problem

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, connection

I have a new problem with tor-browser. Actually  in recent when I open tor-browser an error shown with these description:
"Error starting download:
connection was refused by other side: 111: connection refused.
Are you connected to the internet?"
and I clearly know that I 'm connected to internet.
Time ago (about 1 month) I installed it and I used of tor-browser without any error!
Here is a picture of error to better understand:
[image]

Now how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try deleting tor and then downloading it again. Might be an update issue

Comment: I tried this solution for 2 times but it doesn't work at all. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Another late reply: I was struggling with this, tried every fix (re-install, install latest version via adding @micahflee to apt-repository, etc and couldn't figure out what was wrong. Then I went on VPN. And it worked just fine. Seems to me my ISP was blocking the download.

Comment: You should download it over Tor system.

Answer (score 3):

Late reply: I guess that this happens because of a proxy. In that case go to the settings of torbrowser-launcher with the following command:

```
torbrowser-launcher --settings
```

Then tick ''Download over system Tor'' and click on ''Install Tor Browser''.